# Routing correctly with some reserved functions for a specific controller?

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I have a **function** in a controller `product` that is called `view`

To access that I do (in adressbar of browser) : `product/view/{id}`

Now **I want to change**....

I want to access it with `product/{id}`

This is what I've tried (in routes.php)

```
$route['product/(:any)'] = "product/view/$1";
```

That works, but I have specific function names I want to access, like `product/gallery`. But *with that routing* I always get to the `view`-function of product-controller. When I type product/gallery in the adressbar of the browser I want to call/execute the `gallery`-function of product-controller.

I've tried

```
$route['product/(:num)'] = "product/view/$1";
```

but that didn't work at all

I've also tried to put the code of `view()` inside of `index()`-function, but that resulted in that I hade to access the url like this:

```
product/index/{id}
```

Comment: 'id' is Numeric or Alphanumeric ?. It works only for numeric. Otherwise you should use (:any)

Comment: The thing is that id (productid) could be either numeric or alphanumeric (productname). If I use :any, I can't access product/gallery properly (then the view-function is called and I don't want that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'id' is Numeric or Alphanumeric ?. It works only for numeric. Otherwise you should use (:any)

Or **Not sure**. Try this.

```
$route['product/gallery/(:any)'] = "product/gallery/$1";
$route['product/(:any)'] = "product/view/$1";
```